# How to append metadata to columns in R?

Tags: r, metadata

I am trying to append metadata to columns in R.  I have a large data set, and would like to pull up metadata info in R through comments (or is there somewhere more appropriate?).  I have the metadata typed into single cells in a separate file, and am trying to refer to them when defining comments.

I have tried the following:

```
comment(data$cat)=as.quoted(metadata$catdot)
comment(data$cat)
# NULL
```

this next one I tried to put quotation marks around the text I wanted to pull in

```
comment(data$cat)=as.quoted(metadata$cat)
# Error in parse(text = x) : <text>:1:5: unexpected symbol
# 1: how many
   ^
```

another attempt using quotation marks.  Please ignore the silly text, I'm just testing code with a data set and meta data I made up

```
comment(data$place)=metadata$placequote
# Error in `comment<-`(`*tmp*`, value = list("whether the location is a shelter or a foster home because that is really important the poor little dogs and cats just don't have anywhere else to go maybe they are blind or starving and it's really just such a shame")) : 
# attempt to set invalid 'comment' attribute

comment(data$place)=readChar(metadata$place,nchars=81)
# Error in readChar(metadata$place, nchars = 81) : 
# cannot read from this connection

comment(data$place)=paste(readLines(metadata$place), collapse=" ")
# Error in readLines(metadata$place) : 'con' is not a connection
```

Comment: What do you intend to do with it? `comment` is fine, but you may just want to make up your own `attributes` for the variables.

Comment: My guess? The values in your "metadata" dataset are `factor`s and you need to convert them to `character`s first (using `as.character`). But, without some reproducible example code, hard to say.

Comment: Take a look at http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Data-structures.html#attributes - and particularly the caveat about when attributes are preserved (by default, not often)